# 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, tuples

I've checked every other post about this, but none can fix my issue.

I made a list that holds tuples with an id and a datetime object. Everytime I try to clean up the list with:
`last_encounters = [item for item in last_encounters if item[1] < datetime.utcnow]`
I get the error that `'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable`. It's getting pretty annoying, I tried dicts.. didn't work.

Also tested the item[1], according to my print it is a datetime.

Even tried changing it to `(x,y) for x,y in last_encounters if y < ...` also did NOT work.

Some useful code:

```
list = []
d_t = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(9000000)     
list += [('lel', d_t)]     
list = [item for item in list if item[1] < datetime.utcnow]
```

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: The code you posted won't produce the error you describe at all: `last_encounters` is empty, so the list comp just returns an empty list.  Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: I only added the code where the list is actually modified. I assume that it doesn't loop an empty list? I printed values and it wasn't empty at all. I showed me the values in the tuple item, where the second one was a datetime for sure.

Comment: In your posted code, the very first line sets `last_encounters` to an empty list.  If that isn't what your list contains when it hits the list comprehension, you need to post *that*.

Comment: That's where I initialise the list. I will change the order as it isn't done in this particular order. First it creates the list. Then it adds it and then it loops through it, giving that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `last_encounters += (a, b)`, you are adding two sequences together, `last_encounters` and `(a,b)`.  This means you end up with `a` and `b` stuck on the end of the list, rather than just adding the tuple to the list.

There are two options to fix your problem:

1. Add a sequence containing your tuple:

   ```
    last_encounters += [(d["id"], d["d_t"])]
   ```
2. Or preferably, use the `append` method:

   ```
    last_encounters.append((d["id"], d["d_t"]))
   ```

Comment: Uch, that's it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is the way you add the tuple to the list. Here is an example to show the problem :

```
l = []
l += ("a", "b")
print l

l = []
l.append( ("a", "b"))
print l
```

Which gives :

```
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> [('a', 'b')]
```

So `list+=tuple` is equivalent to calling `list.extend(tuple)` and not `list.append(tuple)` which is what you want.

A side note on the meaning of the exception that was raised :
`X is not subscriptable` means that your are trying to call that syntax `X[some int]` while the object doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `utcnow` as a method `utcnow()`:

```
last_encounters = [item for item in last_encounters if item[1] < datetime.utcnow()]
```

I couldn't reproduce your error with a version of your code, but a version with items in the list lead to this fix.

Comment: I've done that and now it says: can't compare datetime.datetime to str .... odd...

Comment: We need to see what is in the list you are trying to cleanup - you need to add that to your problem description.  It sounds like there are strings not datetimes.

Comment: Trying to reproduce it with ideone. Reproduced: https://ideone.com/uaDRDv